# Do we need to bounce weblogic application server after adding extra logs in a java class

Tags: java, logging, weblogic-10.x

I have an ear deployed in weblogic 10.3.3. I added some logs to a java class and redeployed the ear. However I did not bounce the server after i did that. I am not able to see the logs in the log files. Is it necessary to bounce the server after deploying the changes?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research on the web, I finally decided to bounce the server and the logs started showing. I guess this must be because the server's cache is not getting cleared.